# How can i make an effect of stack of cards moving from one place to another using jquery

Tags: jquery, effect

How can i make an effect of stack of cards moving from one place to another using jquery

somt thing like this http://www.linkedin.com/

I tried this but its not working :

```
   $( "#img2 li" ).each(function() {

    var el = $(this);

    // Make it static
    el.css({
        visibility: 'hidden', // Hide it so the position change isn't visible
        position: 'static'
    });

    // Get the static position
    var end = el.position();

    // Turn it back to absolute
    el.css({
        visibility: 'visible', // Show it
        position: 'absolute'
    }).animate({ // Animate to the static position
        top: end.top,
        left: end.left
    }, function() { // Make it static
        $(this).css('position', 'static');
    });
});
```

Comment: As starter: http://codepen.io/secondfret/pen/Hiwef

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if that is what you want, but you could simply work with switchClass. Of course, in this example you could move the information about the position from the css classes to javascript (you did something similar in your example):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="demo">
    <div class="card card-position">Click this card</div>
    <div id="stack" class="stack-position"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.demo{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin:15px auto;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
}

.card, #stack{
    width:110px;
    height:180px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    position:absolute;
}

.card{
    background: #CCC;
    z-index: 2;
}

.card-position{
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
}

#stack{
    background: #222;
    z-index: 1;
}

.stack-position{
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card').click(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        moveCard(el,350);   
    });
});

function moveCard(el,duration){
    el.switchClass( 
        "card-position", 
        "stack-position", 
        duration
    );
}
```

Hope this somewhat helps you.

Edit: Oh, and please remember that switchClass requires jQuery UI.